# How to proceed rest response to JSON

Tags: java, android, json

I execute async request (`REST query`). Getting response from server side is...

```
[{"id":2,"name":"Flowers"},{"id":3,"name":"Trees"}]
```

I need to parse response string to `JSONObject` and then to

```
ArrayList<Map<String, String>>
```

In my next `async` method of getting data (some code is commented):

```
//async getting data
@Override
public void onSuccessResult(String response) {
    String message;
    Log.d(Constants.LOG, response);
    try {
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

/*
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("id");
            data.clear();
            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length()-1;i++){
                HashMap<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
                JSONArray url = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);
                m.put("name", url.getString(0));
                dataPlants.add(m);

            //sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

*/

    }catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d(Constants.LOG, e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I get the next `exception`:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value
[{"id":2,"name":"Flowers"},{"id":3,"name":"Trees"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

So, how to proceed `response` appropriately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that you are **trying to create a JSONObject from a String that represents a JSONArray**
You need to parse the String as JSONArray.

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
```

should be

```
JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(response);
```

in

```
 jsonResponse = new JSONArray(response);
 //data.clear();
 for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length(); i++) {
     Object obj = jsonResponse.get(i);
     if(obj instanceof JSONObject) {
          HashMap<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();
          JSONObject object = jsonResponse.getJSONObject(i);
          m.put(object.getString("id"), object.getString("name"));
          dataPlants.add(m);
     }
 }
 //sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

@ Edit : **Additionally, I editted the code so there is an object verification there.**
Honestly, whenever treating with JSON files, **you should treat them as objects** and check whether they are an instance of a JSONObject or an instance of a JSONArray, since both have different parsing mechanisms

Comment: @Maksim Good to know that it worked! Mark the answer as accepted so others may find it useful for fixing their bugs. Regards